# Why the driver.getTitle does not matches with the expected result in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
public class LoginAndSearch {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\puren\\Downloads\\Compressed\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("http://www.linkedin.com");
    String a = driver.getTitle();
    if (a=="LinkedIn: Log In or Sign Up")
        System.out.print("Pass");
    else
        System.out.println("Fail");
    driver.close();
 }
}
```

In this code, the "If condition" does not match with the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing for references of String objects. To compare string values change your code snippet as follows:

```
 String a = driver.getTitle();
 if (a.equals("LinkedIn: Log In or Sign Up"))
      System.out.print("Pass");
 else
      System.out.println("Fail");
```

Follow the link for more:

[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, I forget to use 'Equals' method.